# Adding IBAction to a UIAlert

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I was trying to get my UIAlert to do two different actions when the buttons are clicked. When the user clicks restart, the game restarts and when main menu is clicked, the game should go to the main menu. The reset button is working fine but the IBAction keeps giving me errors about switching views.

```
// called when the player touches the "Reset Game" button
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self resetGame];
    }
    else
    {
        - (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender {
            Menu *menuView = [[[menu alloc] init] autorelease];
            [gameView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
            [self presentModalViewController:menuView animated:YES];

        }

    }



    }
```

The reset works fine but I am getting two errors on the IBAction. 'showFlip' undeclared (first use in this function) and  expected ';' before ':' token. Don't understand why it would say this because when I post the IBAction outside of the alertview it works fine.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining a method, not calling one! This code

```
- (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender {
            Menu *menuView = [[[menu alloc] init] autorelease];
            [gameView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
            [self presentModalViewController:menuView animated:YES];

        }
```

should not live inside this function. Pull it out to be

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self resetGame];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showFlip];
    }
}

-(void)showFlip{
    Menu *menuView = [[[menu alloc] init] autorelease];
    [gameView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:menuView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, as you can probably tell i'm pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You should try this:

```
// called when the player touches the "Reset Game" button
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    // the user clicked one of the OK/Cancel buttons
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [self resetGame];
    }
    else
    {
        [self showFlip:nil];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showFlip:(id)sender {
    Menu *menuView = [[[menu alloc] init] autorelease];
    [gameView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self presentModalViewController:menuView animated:YES];
}
```